# Erro de layout no admin do Magento

Tags: magento

O erro é este:

> a:5:{i:0;s:117:"Modelo base "mango/category_attribute_source_tab_mode" não encontrado para o atributo "sw_product_staticblock_tab_1"";i:1;s:4045:"

A história é assim: instalei um tema chamado Mango (que agora está com nome de porto) para um cliente... Suporte deles é muito ruim, deu uns problemas então eu deletei as pastas desse tema de acordo com as pastas que vieram no arquivo zipado do tema. Até então tudo certo. Instalei outro tema, mas agora quando entro na categoria de produtos do magento pra editar apresenta este erro.

Sei que é um erro de layout. Mas em que arquivo deve estar chamando este modelo base que o log apresentou?

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. O tema, além de criar os arquivos na pasta app/design, app/code, skin/base e etc... ele também criou na tabela eav_attribute alguns atributos para criar novas opções nas categorias para exibir no MegaMenu... depois de muito procurar e não ter respostas aqui... encontrei!! Apaguei as entradas referes ao tema da tabela e voltou a funcionar! ;)